# Trouble in moving a data to another database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to move a data to another database. I can already move different fields like integer, varchar **BUT** not **BLOB**

So my form has:

> 1. datagridview = that gets the data from the table (in first database) and where those data are displayed
> 2. button = that triggers the action

My code below gets the data in the table (in the first database) and put it on the datagridview. I need to get the image from the first database then copy it to another database. But when i run my code, the data in the second database is just "System.Drawing.Bitmap" and not the actual image.

I really need to do this as soon as possible. Is there anyone who can help me with this? It will be so much appreciated.

```
Sub getData()
        Try
            Dim Sql = "Select ID, IMG from sample"
            connectionOn()
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConOn)
            Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            While dr.Read = True
                Dim mybytearray As Byte() = dr.Item("IMG")  
                Dim myimage As Image
                Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(mybytearray)
                myimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr(0), myimage)
            End While
            ConOn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are only getting the string indicating the type and not the actual image.   A DataGridview defaults to string and number types and will not store object like images unless a custom column is added to the datagridview.  Instead of trying to put the image into the DataGridView put the image into a datatable  and make the datatable the DataSource of the DataGridView.  Or even better use BulkCopy and copy the First DataBase directly to the Second DataBase.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing images in databases, *especially* if this is for a live system.

Comment: @jdweng i'm trying to sync my online and offline databases. everything is working properly except on images. i'll try to search and understand on how to use datatables (since i'm just new in vb) anyways, thank you very much :)

Comment: @cybermonkey saving only paths in database is prone to data loss that's why i didn't do it

Comment: @MiharuChan Same for saving whole images.